# Qt QHttp Undefined Reference Error

Tags: qt4

I'm new in Qt, I used this code to request a http but i got error!

```
QHttp http;
 HTTPEngine::HTTPEngine(){
  http.setHost("http://google.com");
}
```

[Here is error http://shirazitco.ir/QT.png](http://shirazitco.ir/QT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .pro file add:

```
QT += network
```

Then it will allow you to add the header:

```
#include <QHttp>
```

Re-run qmake to update the project.

Also, have a look at the [Qt Networking Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/examples-network.html) and try to compile those.